# Instantiate 100 classes in a tile based game, or any better solution?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, instantiation, tile

in a tile based game, I store some data via json, and the json file contains the names of classes with their data.

Is it a problem to instantiate a new class each time I want to add a new object? (which ends up to 100 instantiations). I tried to use static classes, but because I add a new object each time, that can differ from the previous one, I need to `instantiate` a new class, so I think the static class is not the right option.

Is there a third option possible?

Comment: Flyweight if the instances are heavy. What do you store in your class?

Comment: @Emil Lundin @dcastro I store simple data such as `x`, `width`, `name`, `secondName`

Comment: Creating 100 objects is generally not a problem, especially if those objects are just storing simple data.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the flyweight pattern wouldn't work here because you couldn't really share objects since they all exist at different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of objects should be multiplied by their sizes. In general 100 objects should not be a problem. It might be a problem if you throw them away and recreate them 60 times a second.

The resulting memory footprint and the amount of garbage collection runs might then be a problem.

Do the math, do not optimize prematurely, and post the results to get more precise advice.

Comment: Thanks Erno, alright then, if I can go with this solution then perfect. I was only wondering if there was a way with static classes. Thanks for your answer

Comment: If you are considering static classes for this you probably don't understand the way classes and objects are managed in the CLR and how selecting static classes would possibly harm your code. I can't see how static classes would reduce memory size by much.